# How to change text color on OnMouseHover in a Dropdown Menu

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdown menu.I want the background and text color to get changed as soon as mouse hover is performed .At present background color is getting changed correctly whereas i am not able to change the text color ..

Here is the fiddle ...
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ku8Mq/)

and Here is the HTML...

```
               <nav>
                <ul>

                    <li><a href="#">ABOUT US</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Photoshop&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Illustrator&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">DreamViewer&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Web Design&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a>

                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>

                </ul>
```

Please help me to solve this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add this css `color: #000;` in class `nav ul ul li a:hover` .

```
 nav ul ul li a:hover{
        color: #000;(added css)
        background: #e6e6e6;
    }
```

Hope it'll help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
nav ul ul li a:hover {
  background: #e6e6e6;
  color:#INSERT HEX;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you just need to add below code.

```
nav ul li ul li:hover > a {
   color: #f00; 
}
```

### [DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/Ku8Mq/2/)